# shortcut to access a value in a drop down box (in web browser)

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, browser, shortcuts

Is there a way to  access a value in a drop down box in Google Chrome?

[image]

Like when i sign up for services I always have to put my country so I have to select the combox and type S. But even still I have to scroll through like 7 to (sometimes) 9 other entries. if i simply type [S] then [I] it will jump to the entries starting with [I] instead of [SI].

I'm wondering is there a shortcut?

Comment: Try typing faster?

Comment: what do you mean? i of course couldn't type anything other than the first letter in a drop down box? then i had to scroll through and point and click with mouse

Comment: look at the image in the question. there isn't anywhere where i could type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do it type pretty quickly.

Comment: what do you mean? i of course couldn't type anything other than the first letter in a drop down box? then i had to scroll through and point and click with mouse

Comment: look at the image in the question. there isn't anywhere where i could type

Comment: Even so, if you just type "peru" while the drop-down box has focus, it'll select Peru. Sometimes it gets a little screwed up if there's a space, like "United Arab Emirates", but in those cases if you just type "United" it'll get you close enough to select an item with the mouse or arrow keys pretty easily.

Comment: *> there isn't anywhere where i could type*. True, but once the box is in focus (i.e. clicked), you can type away. If you type fast enough, it will select the proper option. Of course you will need to know what you want to look for, or start typing [SI] again after [S] alone didn't work.

Comment: this is insane. i didn't know that for years!